# Images from Assets Folder are not working in UWP app

Tags: image, xaml, uwp, windows-phone, frame

[image]

The Images are working in the MainPage, but I'm trying to Integrate it in an Navigational Panel Templete and  the images don't show up. Can anyone suggest me what might be the problems.

The Templete's making use of FRAMES but that should not be the issues.

XAML code

```
<Button Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Assets/donut-icon.png" Style="{StaticResource IconImageStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Donut" Foreground="White" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

Styles Resources

```
 <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="IconImageStyle">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,10,0" />
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I noticed that your page is in your "Pages/Go Nuts" folder, so you should use following URI to get the image.

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/donut-icon.png" />
```

Or

```
<Image Source="/Assets/donut-icon.png" />
```

While using `<Image Source="Assets/donut-icon.png" />` it will search resource in current folder. But there is no such resource in current folder, so it won't work.

Comment: @JayZuo what if it is in Resources folder? In the DRAWABLE icons?

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista I'm not sure what your Resources folder and DRAWABLE icons are. If you have any problem, please feel free to ask a new question with the details of your issue so that we can help you further.

Comment: How to pick the resource in solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322(v=win.10).aspx

Comment: it works well with uwp renderer for xamarin forms also.

Comment: How can you make this work if you're working on a library project? I have a library project that has its own Asset folder and within that lib project, I have xaml files that references images from its own asset folder. And then there's the UWP app project that references the library project.