# Transition uwp button animation through multiple images

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I'd like to have a button that transitions through a sequence of images, thus making the button appear animated.

Currently I created a grid cell of three buttons and they all time just one image of the animation stacked on top of each other.

I'd like to reduce this down to one button:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Tag="2204" Click="Room_Click" Height="60" Width="60">
    <Button.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MyButtonStoryBoard" BeginTime="0:0:0" RepeatBehavior="Forever">

        // animate here

            // what I tried but doesn't work
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0"  RepeatBehavior="Forever"  Storyboard.TargetName="MyButtonStoryBoard" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" >
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                          <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/MapImages/innerRing.png" />
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.03" >
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                           <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/MapImages/middleRing.png" />
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                 <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.06" >
                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                         <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/MapImages/outerRing.png" />
                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                 </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
             </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

        </Storyboard>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

The goal is to do  all the animation in the XAML file. I'd like to know how to do this kind of animation on a button. e.g. think about telling the button to display a GIF and thats what it should look like, but using separate images and not a gif file.

EDIT:

Here is my second attempt. But Im not able to change the background value:

```
<Button x:Name="BlowMoldingButton" Tag="2204" Click="Room_Click" Height="60" Width="60" >
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
             <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>

                     // this is not working
                     <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BlowMoldingButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="/Assets/MapImages/innerRing.png" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Why do you need a button? You click on it and the image changes?

Comment: @JustinXL it's an animated button that cycles through different images. It's autoplayed when the button loads.

Comment: but what's it to do with a button? You can use a Grid to do that too.

Comment: Right, but instead of specifying a lot of grid code, I could just point to one storyboard animation.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. A Grid I'd much lighter than a Button, and can invoke animations too. You are using a button for the wrong reason. You should ask how to cycle through and display a list of images. Putting a button there is just confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of [Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_Background) property is [Brush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.brush), so in the `Value` of `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`, we should provide a `Brush` not a `String`. And as you want to use images as background, the `Brush` should be [Image​Brush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageBrush).

So you can change your code like the following (for test purpose, I changed the `Duration` and `KeyTime`):

```
<Button x:Name="BlowMoldingButton" Tag="2204"  Height="60" Width="60" >
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:3" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetName="BlowMoldingButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" >
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/MapImages/innerRing.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" >
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/MapImages/middleRing.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" >
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/MapImages/outerRing.png" />
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't seem to load the images for me.

Comment: @jefhai This works well in my side. Please check your assets and make sure you have the right images under "Assets/MapImages" folder and these images' "Build Action" has set to "Content".

Comment: @jefhai Also you may using `ms-appx:///Assets/MapImages/innerRing.png` instead of `Assets/MapImages/innerRing.png` to avoid problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33517361/5506161).

Answer (score 0):

Content is the insides, in your case the button, and the background is the view.

Try this:
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
instead this:
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content"

**EDITED**
Try to make with styles:

```
            <Button x:Name="BlowMoldingButton" Tag="2204" Click="Room_Click" Height="60" Width="60" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />



            <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0"  RepeatBehavior="Forever"  Storyboard.TargetName="MyButtonStoryBoard" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/MapImages/innerRing.png" />
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.03" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/MapImages/middleRing.png" />
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.06" >
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="Assets/MapImages/outerRing.png" />
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```